# hibernate lock table before reading and deleting rows

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table which keeps getting updated. Every 30 seconds I read the values from these table to process something and then delete it. All is good, though I am worried that between reading and deleting, new rows might get inserted, which means I havent read them yet, but it will be deleted.
I was thinking of putting a lock of this table for the time i read it and delete the entry, but I see people have advised against it.
Also, I need to make sure, if I lock it, the items to be inserted remains in cache somehow and gets inserted when lock is gone. I am not sure what is the best practice and how to do it.

Comment: You have literally stated that you want to have synchronized access to the database every 30 seconds (for whatever reasons) then just do it and put a table lock. Other accessors will just have to wait untill lock if lifted. Votes agains it are just due to a obvious performance impact that it will have by the means of whole world have to wait for the processing to be done - which is your requirement here.

Comment: If you are using an auto_increment id field, you can get the last row id you read and delete only those with id <= read_id

Comment: @nazim, this might work. let me try

Comment: This would be a good application for a message queue. As you add new rows to the database, also add the id's to the queue. The worker that processes your data takes id's from the queue, processes the row for that id, and then deletes that row. Therefore the processing code knows exactly which id's to read and delete. If new rows are added concurrently, they are added to the queue, and therefore are read next time the processor runs.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks. i agree. but i have simple needs to as simple soultion is fine

Comment: @nazim, it works, can yoy please post the answer, so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an `auto_increment` id field, you can get the last row id you read and delete only those with `id <= $read_id`